# Keras: Using Dice coefficient Loss Function, val loss is not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

### Problem

I am doing two classes image segmentation, and I want to use loss function of dice coefficient. However validation loss is not improved. How to Solve these problem?

### what I did

Using the mothod of one-hot encoding, Processed label image and it has not include backgroung label.

### Code

Shape of X is (num of data, 256, 256, 1) # graysacle

Shape of y is (num of data, 256, 256, 2) # two class and exclude background label

````
one_hot_y = np.zeros((len(y), image_height, image_width, 2))
for i in range(len(y)):
  one_hot = to_categorical(y[i])
  one_hot_y[i] = one_hot[:,:,1:] 
one_hot_y.shape  #->  (566, 256, 256, 2)

#### <-- Unet Model --> ####

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Concatenate, Conv2DTranspose
from keras import Model

def unet(image_height, image_width, num_classes):
    # inputs = Input(input_size)
    inputs = Input(shape=(image_height, image_width, 1),name='U-net')
    
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = Concatenate()([Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv5), conv4])
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = Concatenate()([Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv6), conv3])
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = Concatenate()([Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv7), conv2])
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = Concatenate()([Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv8), conv1])
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    outputs = Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), activation='softmax')(conv9)
    
    return Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])```


#### <-- Dice Score --> ####

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
  y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
  intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
  return (2. * intersection + 0.0001) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + 0.0001)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)```


#### <-- Fit the Model --> ####

from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
unet_model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=[dice_coef_loss],metrics=[dice_coef])
hist = unet_model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,validation_data=(X_val,y_val), callbacks=[checkpoint,earlystopping])
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your experience. I used the Oxford-IIIT Pets database whose label has three classes: 1: Foreground, 2: Background, 3: Not classified. If class 1 ("Foreground") is removed as you did, then the val_loss does not change during the iterations. On the other hand, if the "Not classified" class is removed, the optimization seems to work. The model fails to discriminate between "Background" and "Not classified", which is conceivable.
Besides, there is a small error in the calculation of the dice coefficient:  In the denominator, you need to take the sum of the *squares*. It doesn't change anything for y_true but for y_pred it does.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
Maybe my explaination is not enough to understands. It is almost same as you said, but what I did is similar to instance segmentation. I have two instance in my image, its kind of you have one dog and one cat in one image. And then one image have three labels, each label represent 0-background, 1-dog, 2-cat. After the One Hot Encoding, It will have three channels(I am not sure it is right to say like this), and What I removed is "0-background" labels from images. When I train like this, val_loss is not changing.

Comment: About the calculation of the dice coefficient, you means I have to take the sum of the squares in denominator, so  formula have to be a "(2. * intersection + 0.0001) / ((K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f))**2 + 0.0001)" ? Is it right?

Comment: I'm not sure actually, in most documents they don't put the square, but on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) , a general formula for non-binary vectors is provided: 2* |a . b| / |a|**2 + |b|**2

Comment: OK, Thank you! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why your code doesn't work, but I can tell you the way I do it. Differences are that I exclude the background and encode the target inside the dice coef calculation function.

Then I define my Dice coefficient as follows:

```py
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1):
    # flatten
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    # one-hot encoding y with 3 labels : 0=background, 1=label1, 2=label2
    y_true_f = K.one_hot(K.cast(y_true_f, np.uint8), 3)
    y_pred_f = K.one_hot(K.cast(y_pred_f, np.uint8), 3)
    # calculate intersection and union exluding background using y[:,1:]
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f[:,1:]* y_pred_f[:,1:], axis=[-1])
    union = K.sum(y_true_f[:,1:], axis=[-1]) + K.sum(y_pred_f[:,1:], axis=[-1])
    # apply dice formula
    dice = K.mean((2. * intersection + smooth)/(union + smooth), axis=0)
    return dice

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1-dice_coef
```

Comment: Tahnk you for your comment!! I changed my code to your dice coef calculation function. but there is `ValueError` when Fit the model. I think I have to fix somewhere to make it work.
However the difference between yours and mine is you did one-hot encoding in dice_coef function, and I did it before fitting the model. So what I wondering is that order of one-hot encoding step influence the results.

Comment: Did you achieve adapting this code ? I choosed *not* to one-hot encode the original data because i usually use data augmentation while fitting the models that do the encoding. But as you dont do such a thing, I think you can use your already-encoded data and just remove the two lines with K.one_hot

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove the two lines with K.one_hot and trained the model. However validation loss is not improving.
When Using U-net model, can I make the y(label) as two class without background, so it has (num of data, image height, image width, num of class(2)). I made y data as this shape before fitting the model.

Comment: Ok... what does your results look like ? Are you sure that the problem comes from your loss function, and that you are not in an overfitting case, or something like that ?

Comment: Umm.. Let me check.. I am not 100% sure that the problem comes from loss function, however when I use "categorical crossentropy" as loss, model trains very well. Well.. I have to check for it later time. It works when I use another loss function. Thank you for your helps!!

Answer (score -1):

I was also confused about this problem until I understood the following code！！！！

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras import backend as K


def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f* y_pred_f)
    val = (2. * intersection + K.epsilon()) / (K.sum(y_true_f * y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f * y_pred_f) + K.epsilon())
    return 1. - val


arr1 = np.array([[[9.6,0.6,0.3],
                  [0.3,0.5,0.5]],
                 [[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                  [0.5,0.5,0.5]],
                 [[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                 [0.5,0.5,0.5]],
                 [[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                 [0.5,0.5,0.5]]])

arr2= np.array([[[9.6,0.6,0.3],
                  [0.3,0.5,0.5]],
                 [[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                  [0.5,0.5,0.5]],
                 [[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                 [0.5,0.5,0.5]],
                 [[0.5,0.5,0.5],
                 [0.5,0.5,0.5]]])

loss = dice_loss(arr1,arr2)
print(loss)
```